# Strange behave of ruby attr_accessor

Tags: ruby, attr-accessor

I have this block of code:

```
class CallMe
  attr_accessor :a, :b, :c

  def self.start(*args)
     self.new(*args).get_answer
  end

  def initialize(a,b,c)
    @a = a
    @b = b
    @c = c
  end

  def get_answer 
    if c
      b = nil
    else
      return b 
    end
   end
end
answer = CallMe.start(1,2,nil)
```

Why when i run it in irb i always get `answer = nil` even logic case is get b value that is 2

Comment: `b = nil` => `self.b = nil`

Comment: i know that self.b = nil, but why ? 
it should be 2 , i didn't enter the if positive branch? 
add `puts b` before `if c` to understand my question my friend

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Variable Hoisting** effect is used in many languages. For Ruby it is described in the [official documentation](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.4.0/syntax/assignment_rdoc.html#label-Local+Variables+and+Methods):

> The local variable is created when the parser encounters the assignment, not when the assignment occurs

So, `get_answer` method creates **local** variable `b` regardless to value of `c`. **And** assigns local variable `b` to `nil` while creating. Then `get_answer` returns local variable `b` which is always `nil`.

Correct method:

```
def get_answer
  c ? self.b = nil : b
end
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because in context of `if` statement you actually redefine `b` when you type `b = nil`. For Ruby, it's not clear either you want to call object's method `:b` or to create a new variable `b`. In such cases, priority always goes from the global to the closest context, in this case - to context inside of `if` block.

If you'll change

```
if c
  b = nil
else
  return b
end

# to 
if c
  # b = nil
  # or
  self.b = nil
else
  return b
```

You'll notice it works as you expected.